# How to create counter with unique sequence

Tags: digital-logic, flipflop, counter

I have a sequence: 001, 110, 010, 001, 110,  etc.

Although there are 3 bits that I want to represent, only 2 are needed for states (3 states). What I get confused with, is utilizing only 2 state bits if we need 3 output bits. Can anyone clarify this?

Answer (score 2):

U have three states so create a mod-3 counter first.
for that first make a normal 2 bit counter. Take both its output, NAND it and connect it back to reset of both the flip_flops. Counter will start from 00 then 01, 10 and when it reaches 11 it will resets itself (for active low) and start from 00.

Now you a mod-3 counter. Next step is to design is combinational circuit for each bit. Counter outputs should be to combinational circuits.

Take bit by bit. Your sequence 001, 110, 010. Take LSB fisrt, it is 1 only in first state. Counter output is input of combinational circuit, so design a logic circuit that will give 1 only for the input combination 00 (single NAND Gate). Use the same method to design other two bits.

Answer (score 0):

With such little information I'm not sure what the context is but I'll throw this out there...

If you have 3 states then these three states can be represented with the first two (least significant) bits. So, only those two bits change and you get your state. For example, state 0 = 000, state 1 = 001, and state 2 = 010. That's how a sequential state machine would work. The leftover (MSB) bit wouldn't be needed in this case unless you wanted to use it for some other representation.

Now if you are trying to represent three states using three bits then you are assigning a bit per state, such as bit 0 = state 0, bit 1 = state 1, and bit 2 = state 2. Let's say you can be in two or even three states at once, then those states can be represented using all three bits. For example, 010 would mean that state 1 is active, 011 would mean that state 0 and state 1 are active, and 101 would mean that state 2 and state 0 are active, etc.

Hope that helps!

Comment: Thank you for your response!

I'm still confused as to how this would be represented visually. If I use Q as my state bits, and Q+ as my next-states, you say that I only need Q1 and Q0, however, I'm confused on how to represent numbers such as 110 without Q2.

The next-state truth table is necessary for creating MPOS and MSOP equations for the outputs.

Comment: This smells like a homework assignment, yes? I guess I'm confused about what you are trying to do. Can you post the exact question/problem you have been presented with?

Comment: I think the third bit is your input bit, which is needed for the next-state truth table. Depending on the input and your current state, you'd get one of the 3 states.